# what is meaning of cp %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 in batch file

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file what does this mean?

```
cp %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Are there any good tutorials for beginners for batch programming?

Comment: Where did you get this code? `cp` is not a valid batch command.

Comment: improve formatting and phrasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%X` means 'Xth' argument to the batch file.
There fore %1 ,%2 , ... are the 1st, 2nd.. arguments respectively.

So `cp %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`  will copy the files given as argment 1 to 8 to the destination given as the last argument(i.e 9th)
*(note that it's not not necessarily need to give nine arguments here. say only 6 args are given ; then the destination will be the 6th argument)*

 This is a good place to satart with [computerhope.com/batch](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm)